# How to add space or tab to format text in Paragraph docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I need to add space or tab into a paragraph, I can't use table because on the left I need to add a table, so it will became a nested table.

I try

```
//Paragraph without spaces or tabs
//Paragraph       with spaces or tabs

P paragraph = factory.createP();
paragraph.getContent().add(factory.createTabs());
paragraph.getContent().add(factory.createRTab());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docx4j webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html) or [Helper Word AddIn](https://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-helper-addin-v3-3-available-t2393.html) will answer this for you.

Here is the code I generated;  for extra space (forcing it to use a separate run):

```
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Paragraph</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">      </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>that was some space.</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Assuming P p:

```
       // Create object for r
        R r = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text); 
            r.getContent().add( textWrapped); 
                text.setValue( "Paragraph"); 
        // Create object for r
        R r3 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r3); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text3 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped3 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text3); 
            r3.getContent().add( textWrapped3); 
                text3.setValue( "      "); 
                text3.setSpace( "preserve"); 
        // Create object for r
        R r5 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r5); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text5 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped5 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text5); 
            r5.getContent().add( textWrapped5); 
                text5.setValue( "that was some space.");
```

Using tabs, XML:

```
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Paragraph</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:tab/>
            <w:t>that was a tab</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Assuming P p:

```
        // Create object for r
        R r = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text); 
            r.getContent().add( textWrapped); 
                text.setValue( "Paragraph"); 
        // Create object for r
        R r2 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r2); 
            // Create object for tab (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            R.Tab rtab = wmlObjectFactory.createRTab(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.R.Tab> rtabWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRTab(rtab); 
            r2.getContent().add( rtabWrapped); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text2 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped2 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text2); 
            r2.getContent().add( textWrapped2); 
                text2.setValue( "that was a tab");
```

You don't actually need all the JAXBElements the generated code inserts in this case, so you can clean that up a bit if you want.

And by the way, as an aside, the docx format does allow you to nest a table in a tc if you want :-)

Comment: I try to add Tbl object to a Tc Object, but after that I export the word file, when I open it Word say me that document is “malformed” although nested table is well displayed

Comment: You'll need to open a separate question for that (accepting this answer if it answers the original question), and post the outer table's XML.

Comment: Ok thanks, I try
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped3 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text3); 
            r3.getContent().add( textWrapped3); 
                text3.setValue( "      "); 
                text3.setSpace( "preserve"); 
and it works. Yesterday I found  a solution that say about setSpace, but it doesn't work because JAXBElement is not mentioned.
Now I open a question for nested table